# regex of numbers

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing in bash, this script is supposed to output 'success', but it did not. Is the regex for numbers wrong?

```
var=5
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[:digit:]$ ]]; then 
    echo success
fi
```

Thnx!

Comment: `[[ "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]`

Comment: Got it! Thnx anubhava!

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put `[:digit:]` inside a character class:

```
var=5
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]; then 
    echo success
fi
```

Also note that if you want to match multi digit numbers (`> 9`) you will need to use the plus metacharacter (`+`):

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 
    echo success
fi
```

Comment: In terms of naming, I think that `[:digit:]` is a character class but it needs to go inside a bracket expression `[]`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the character class `[:digit:]` inside bracket expression `[]`:

```
[[ "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]
```

In ASCII locale, this is necessarily equivalent to:

```
[[ "$var" =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]
```